# Paste Image from Excel to Word in a specific placeholder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm working with the below code that copies and pastes a bunch of named ranges from Excel to Word as pictures which already saves me a bunch of time.

To really cap it off I'm wondering if there is a way to insert these images at set places within a word document?

```
Sub copypaste()

    'Create new word document
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add()

    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim rtarget As Word.Range
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Loop Through names
    For intCounter = 1 To wbBook.Names.Count
       Debug.Print wbBook.Names(intCounter)

       With objDoc
            Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)

            'Insert page break if not first page
            If intCounter > 1 Then rtarget.insertbreak Type:=wdPageBreak

            'Write name to new page of word document
            rtarget.Text = wbBook.Names(intCounter).Name & vbCr

            'Copy data from named range
            Range(wbBook.Names(intCounter)).Copy
            Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
            rtarget.PasteSpecial , DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
       End With
    Next intCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. • Not the answer you expected? Then please show how you tried ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)) to do that and where exactly you got stuck or errors (at least show what you have researched so far). Finally ask a question according [ask] that we can answer properly. Otherwise this is just posting code and a requirement to extend it, but SO is no free code writing service.

Comment: So how would the code identify those 'set places'? You haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154690/trying-to-create-an-enclosing-bookmark-after-pasting-a-picture-from-excel-into-w/67155448#67155448